# AWK doesn't work on first row delimited by ^A

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a file looks similar like this(^A is non printing character and below is the view in VI), columns delimited by ^A and rows terminated by \n.

```
# input
2013-10-07 10:40:14.170976^Awww.abc.com/0
2013-10-07 10:40:14.171074^Awww.abc.com/1
2013-10-07 10:40:14.171101^Awww.abc.com/2
2013-10-07 10:40:14.171133^Awww.abc.com/3
2013-10-07 10:40:14.171156^Awww.abc.com/4
...
```

You can recreate the file using a python script below:

```
# test.py
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(10):
    print chr(1).join(str(elem) for elem in [datetime.now(), 'www.abc.com/' + str(i)])
```

Then

```
python test.py > input
```

I tried to get the first column(timestamp) of the file using awk.

```
cat input | awk 'FS="\x01"{print $1}'

2013-10-07
2013-10-07 10:40:14.171074
2013-10-07 10:40:14.171101
2013-10-07 10:40:14.171133
2013-10-07 10:40:14.171156
...
```

Somehow, the first row skipped the part after the timestamp, any one knows what I did wrong. 
Thank you!

Comment: +1 for replicable test case! Good luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because those variables have to be set before beginning to process input files, in a `BEGIN` block, like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\x01" } {print $1}' input
```

Comment: +1: Or `awk -F $'\1' '{print $1}'`, using a `bash` notation for control-A and setting the field separator on the command line.